Replacing string.Split(string[]) with string.Split(char[])
I've noticed that in our code, we have a lot of calls to string.Split(string[],StringSplitOptions) like this:
input.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

or like this:
input.Split(new string[] { "\r", "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

My intuition tells me that I can replace them all with something like this to improve readability (and possibly improve performance, although I don't care about that so much), and that there will be no side-effects:
static readonly string CrLfStrings = new char[] { '\r', '\n' };
input.Split(CrLfStrings, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

In fact, my intuition tells me that, for any set of characters SC, if string.Split(string[],StringSplitOptions) is called with RemoveEmptyEntries and a set of strings that includes all the one-character strings of SC, and where all remaining strings are composed only of characters in SC, I could replace it with a call to string.Split(char[],StringSplitOptions) with RemoveEmptyEntries and SC and there would be no side effects.
Is my hunch correct? Can it be proven? If so, I then I can happily make the replacement everywhere, even if I don't understand the surrounding code.
In other words, will the Compare method below return true for any non-null string? I am not very interested in edge cases where one would run out of memory and the other would not.
using System;
using System.Linq;

private static bool Compare(string input)
{
    string[] prev = null;
    var funcs = new Func<string, string[]>[] { Split0, Split1, Split2 };
    for (int i = 0; i < funcs.Length; i++)
    {
        var curr = funcs[i](input);
        if (i != 0 && !(curr.SequenceEqual(prev)))
        {
            return false;
        }
        prev = curr;
    }
    return true;
}

private static string[] Split0(string input) =>
    input.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
private static string[] Split1(string input) =>
    input.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
private static string[] Split2(string input) =>
    input.Split(new string[] { "\r", "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


You could look into Benchmark.net and test the different implementations

@MichaëlHompus I tried it out in a test program and threw the following strings at it; it seemed to work. I'm wondering if I missed any cases though.
"x", "Hello,\rworld!", "Hello,\r\n\rworld!", "\r\n\r\nHello,\r\n\rworld!", "\r"

You can just submit a string and .Net will use the overload that matches IEnumerable<char>, like this: input.Split("\r\n", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

If its readability you want, perhaps make an extension method:public static class Ext{ public static string[] Lines(this string x) => x.Split(['\r', '\n'], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); }, now you can say myStr.Lines().Whatever...

Look at StringTokenizer

Using char won't improve readability but will increase the number of empty items that have to be eliminated. Real readability gains will come from using array syntax like x.Split(["\r\n", "\n"]. Do use BenchmarkDotNet to check if there are any real performance or memory gains. And make sure you add StringReader. Built-in classes are heavily optimized to avoid generating temporary strings

Two more candidates for testing:

You can just submit a string and .NET will use the overload that matches char[], like this:
 input.Split("\r\n", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


But for my money, I'd use a StringReader:


// IMO a variation of this method should be part of StringReader out of the box
public static IEnumerable<string> AsLines(this string input)
{
    string line = null;
    using var rdr = new System.IO.StringReader(input);
    while (null != (line = rdr.ReadLine())
    {
        yield return line;        
    }
}

and then:
foreach(var line in input.AsLines().Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)))
{
   // do something with each line
}


(For fun, the proposed variations):
// as instance methods of the StringReader type:
public IEnumerable<string> ReadLines()
{
    string line = null;
    while (null != (line = this.ReadLine())
    {
        yield return line;
    }
}

public string[] ReadAllLines()
{
    return this.ReadLines().ToArray();
}

But there are probably ways to do this using Span<char> with MUCH greater performance, and I'd expect they'd want the Async variants as well.

a variation of this method should be part of StringReader out of the box - with .net being open source, and your community standing, if you can't make it happen noone can!

I'm also dreaming about Span-based options for a long time. Dreams come true! MemoryExtensions.Split
